# Excel: filter/delete certain numbers in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help,

I have excel with numbers in 2 columns for example:

```
10   10
20   2010, 2011
30   30100, 30200,30500
40   40
```

And the result I want to have is as follows:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
10,11
100,200,500
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

So if the result between column 1 and 2 is 0 to have numbers from 1 to 9.

Is there a way to do this??

Comment: Edit your question to clarify what is the second column, because second and third row of your second column contain multiple values. Also clarify what you man by "result" in the sentence "So if the result between column 1 and 2 is 0 to have numbers from 1 to 9."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the characters in column one from any part of the values in column two, then try:

```
=IF(A1=B1,"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1," ",""),A1,""))
```

If you only want to remove the column one values from the beginning part of the column two values, then try:

```
=IF(B1=C1,"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9",MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&C1," ",""),"," &B1,","),2,99))
```

Note that, for the final result, I removed the spaces as you showed in your example.

Using Second formula:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ron, yes i want to remove the value of the first column just from the beginning part of column two. I tried both formulas and the output was the same. The problem now is if I have 30 in column one and 3030 in column two i need to have only the first 30 removed.

Comment: @DamjanNikolovski There was a typo in the second formula.  Now corrected and should do what you want

Comment: Yes now its working perfectly. Please let me know if there is some option to give you thumbs up or something like that as I'm new to this forum. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @DamjanNikolovski You should be able to click on a check mark to mark my response as "the answer". ...  Ah, I see you just did that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA approach:

```
Function AdHoc(x As Variant, y As Variant) As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String

    v = Split(y, ",")
    If Val(x) = Val(v(0)) Then
        s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
    Else
        For i = 0 To UBound(v)
            v(i) = Mid(Trim(v(i)), 1 + Len(Trim(Str(x))))
        Next i
        s = Join(v, ",")
    End If
    AdHoc = s
End Function
```

If this is entered into a standard code module, then `AdHoc` can be used directly in the worksheet:

[image]

In the above I simply entered `=adhoc(A1,B1)` in cell `C1` and then copied down.

Comment: Thank you John, but actually this VBA aproach is new to me, so it would be great if you can you specify how can i open the vba paste yhe code and then call it from excel.

Comment: @DamjanNikolovski See this about how to open the VBA editor and insert a module: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html#visual-basic-editor . Once you create a new module, just copy-paste the code into it and it should directly work from the spreadsheet. You would need to save the spreadsheet as a `.xlsm` (macro-enabled) workbook rather than a `.xlsx`. That link should hopefully be enough to go on.